# Android - Bluetooth find device error

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm new here so I apologize if I wrote something bad
I got some error in my code that should find some but device (in Eclipse it looks ok but it shows some Force Quit while I'm clicking button Find Device :(

**Code**

```
package com.moj.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Bluetooth extends Activity{

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth);
        Button bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btbutton1);
        Button bFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btbutton2);

        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                BluetoothStart();       
            }
        });

        bFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Register the BroadcastReceiver
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();


            }
        });


    }


    public void BluetoothStart() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                //Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE), REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }
    }


    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            EditText te = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                te.setText(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant run this on Emulator because it doesn't have support for Bluetooth. You need to test it on a real device.

And don't forget to include Bluetooth permission in manifest.

```
<manifest ... >
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: I've got this permission but code doesn't work corretly (Whet I clicked button bFind some ForceQuit is emmited)

Comment: are you running it on emulator ?